# ¿Cómo imprimir string con asm! en rust?

Tags: rust

Estoy creando un código para poder imprimir texto en pantalla con el macro de rust (asm!) y este es el código:

```
fn printmsg(string: &str) {
    let length: usize = string.len();
    unsafe {
        asm!("syscall" :: "{rax}"(1), "{rdi}"(1), "{rsi}"(&string), "{rdx}"(length));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "hello world!";
    printmsg(s);
}
```

Cuando hago correr el código me imprime letras aleatorias...

¿Qué hago para que me imprima "hello world!" y no otra cosa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un *string slice* consiste en un puntero a la cadena y una longitud. Si pasas la salida por `od` obtienes:

```
$ cargo run 2> /dev/null | od -tx1
0000000 90 48 30 8c e6 7f 00 00 0c 00 00 00
0000014
```

Los 8 primeros son un puntero, los siguientes (0x0c = 12) son la longitud. Otra forma de verlo:

```
 $ cargo run | perl -ne 'printf "ptr: %x, len: %d\n", unpack "QL"'
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target/debug/printasm`
ptr: 7f706ab51890, len: 12
```

Para acceder al puntero a la cadena real, se puede usar el método `as_ptr`().

```
asm!("syscall" :: "{rax}"(1), "{rdi}"(1), "{rsi}"(string.as_ptr()), "{rdx}"(length));
```

Ten en cuenta que esta cadena no está terminado por un byte NUL, así que si quisieras pasarla a una librería escrita en C o similar habría que convertirla a `CString` del módulo `std::ffi::CString`.